# Grep - print lines until line is empty

Tags: logging, grep

In grep, is there option to show output until line meets some regex? In example

foo.log:

```
request1: POST /foo
params
some payload

request1: tag
some payload

request2: POST /foo
params
some payload
```

I would like to `grep` `foo.log` to get all information about request1, like this:

```
request1: POST /foo
params
some payload

request1: tag
some payload
```

Is this possible (something like -A options) or I just need to use regexps??

Comment: In AIX I have sometimes seen `grep -p` that prints the whole paragraph of the matching line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '/request1/' foo.log
```

Comment: WOW, thanks a lot! I just had a problem with `cat foo.log | xargs awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '/request1/'` do you know why?

Comment: No need to `cat file | xargs awk`, just `awk file`. That is, the command Kent posted is enough, will do all that is required.

Comment: @fedorqui is right. Slawosz, just cp my line, and replace the filename with your file.

Comment: @Kent but what about ie. `tail -100` etc?

Comment: I don't get what you were asking, @Sławosz. `tail -100` for what?

Comment: @Kent sorry, I mean pipeing like `tail -100 file | xargs awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '/request1/'`

Comment: @Sławosz did you test with it? what problem did you have?